# .insertBefore() works in one direction, but not another

Tags: javascript, dom

I feel silly asking this because I'm very proficient with JavaScript, but I must be low on caffeine. In preparing an answer to another post, I'm struggling to understand why I cannot move (using `parentNode.insertBefore(nodeToMove, referenceNode)`) a row down in a table, while moving it up works as expected.

As you can see in the `console`, all variables are populated as expected and required and I am reaching the correct `else if` block as I should.

**NOTE:** If you open your actual developer console, you'll be able to expand the `tr` listed in the report to verify that the right rows are being referenced.

```js
// Get all the row elements and attach a click event handler for each of them
var rows = document.querySelectorAll("tr");

Array.prototype.slice.call(rows).forEach(function(r){
  r.addEventListener("click", swap);
});

function swap(evt) {
  // Get reference to the <tbody> element in the <table>
  var tbody = document.querySelector("table").querySelector("tbody");
 
  // Get the name of the class on the clicked element. This determines direction.
  var direction = evt.srcElement.classList.toString();
  
  // Get current row, previous row and next row references
  var cur = evt.currentTarget;
  var prev = cur.previousElementSibling;
  var next = cur.nextElementSibling;
  
  // DEBUGGING REPORT: ***********************************
  console.clear();
  console.log("Direction: " +  direction);
  console.log("Current row: ",  evt.currentTarget);
  console.log("Previous row: ", prev);
  console.log("Next row: ", next);
  // *****************************************************

  // Check to see if up was clicked and if there is a previous row to move clicked row to
  if(direction === "up" && prev){
     tbody.insertBefore(cur, prev);  // Move the current row up
  } else if(direction === "down" && next) {
     console.log("down was clicked and there is a next row to go after");
     // Move the current row down
     tbody.insertBefore(cur, next);  // <-- All variables are as expected, but no move!
  }
}
```

```css
span { text-decoration:underline; color:blue; cursor:pointer; }
```

```html
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <td>Row A</td>
        <td>
            <span class="up">Up</span>
            <span class="down">Down</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row B</td>
        <td>
            <span class="up">Up</span>
            <span class="down">Down</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row C</td>
        <td>
            <span class="up">Up</span>
            <span class="down">Down</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**EDIT**:

Thanks to @David Thomas for the right diagnosis. Actually, the answer was even easier than his, I just needed to swap the arguments to: `insertBefore(next, cur);`

```js
// Get all the row elements and attach a click event handler for each of them
var rows = document.querySelectorAll("tr");

Array.prototype.slice.call(rows).forEach(function(r){
  r.addEventListener("click", swap);
});

function swap(evt) {
  // Get reference to the <tbody> element in the <table>
  var tbody = document.querySelector("table").querySelector("tbody");
 
  // Get the name of the class on the clicked element. This determines direction.
  var direction = evt.srcElement.classList.toString();
  
  // Get current row, previous row and next row references
  var cur = evt.currentTarget;
  var prev = cur.previousElementSibling;
  var next = cur.nextElementSibling;
  
  // DEBUGGING REPORT: ***********************************
  console.clear();
  console.log("Direction: " +  direction);
  console.log("Current row: ",  evt.currentTarget);
  console.log("Previous row: ", prev);
  console.log("Next row: ", next);
  // *****************************************************

  // Check to see if up was clicked and if there is a previous row to move clicked row to
  if(direction === "up" && prev){
     tbody.insertBefore(cur, prev);  // Move the current row up
  } else if(direction === "down" && next) {
     console.log("down was clicked and there is a next row to go after");
     // Move the current row down
     tbody.insertBefore(next, cur);  // <-- swap the arguments!
  }
}
```

```css
span { text-decoration:underline; color:blue; cursor:pointer; }
```

```html
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <td>Row A</td>
        <td>
            <span class="up">Up</span>
            <span class="down">Down</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row B</td>
        <td>
            <span class="up">Up</span>
            <span class="down">Down</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row C</td>
        <td>
            <span class="up">Up</span>
            <span class="down">Down</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of the line:

```
tbody.insertBefore(cur, next);
```

You're inserting the `cur` node before the `next` node, which means you're moving the node to the same position it already occupies; so instead try:

```
tbody.insertBefore(cur, next.nextSibling);
```

```js
// Get all the row elements and attach a click event handler for each of them
var rows = document.querySelectorAll("tr");

Array.prototype.slice.call(rows).forEach(function(r) {
  r.addEventListener("click", swap);
});

function swap(evt) {
  // Get reference to the <tbody> element in the <table>
  var tbody = document.querySelector("table").querySelector("tbody");

  // Get the name of the class on the clicked element. This determines direction.
  var direction = evt.srcElement.classList.toString();

  // Get current row, previous row and next row references
  var cur = evt.currentTarget;
  var prev = cur.previousElementSibling;
  var next = cur.nextElementSibling;

  // DEBUGGING REPORT: ***********************************
  console.clear();
  console.log("Direction: " + direction);
  console.log("Current row: ", evt.currentTarget);
  console.log("Previous row: ", prev);
  console.log("Next row: ", next);
  // *****************************************************

  // Check to see if up was clicked and if there is a previous row to move clicked row to
  if (direction === "up" && prev) {
    tbody.insertBefore(cur, prev); // Move the current row up
  } else if (direction === "down" && next) {
    console.log("down was clicked and there is a next row to go after");
    // Move the current row down
    tbody.insertBefore(cur, next.nextSibling); // <-- All variables are as expected, but no move!
  }
}
```

```css
span {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>Row A</td>
    <td>
      <span class="up">Up</span>
      <span class="down">Down</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row B</td>
    <td>
      <span class="up">Up</span>
      <span class="down">Down</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row C</td>
    <td>
      <span class="up">Up</span>
      <span class="down">Down</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pb9hsc8d/).

Comment: Duh! Actually, all that is needed is to swap the arguments: `insertBefore(next, cur)`. Thanks. Coffee break time!

Comment: @ScottMarcus Also check if `next.nextSibling` exist.

Comment: No worries; it hadn't actually occurred to me, yet, that swapping the arguments might be easier (or just as functional) :)

Comment: @TodorSimeonov If you look at the code, you'll see I'm already doing that.

Comment: @Todor: it doesn't matter whether it exists or not: "*If referenceNode is `null`, the [`next` node] is inserted at the end of the list of child nodes."* - from the [MDN documentation for `insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore).